# What is the name of the word of the feeling of almost getting hit by something? like a near miss but emotionally?

Tags: expressions

I am writing a personal narritave for my freshman writing class and I just cant come up with the word that fits at the end of this. "Then out of the blue comes a curveball, something so unexpected she’s completely stunned. He came out to her. He’s AroAce. With that she felt (insert word here)"

Comment: It's not clear to me what the near miss was here. You say she's stunned but at the same time say she fortunately avoided some catastrophe. Can you elaborate? (And is *aromantic* / *asexual* really considered a "coming out" now?)

Comment: Perhaps the near miss is the woman's shock and disappointment of her hopes of a sexual/romantic relationship being dashed by a few words, yet relief that she hadn't yet expressed those feelings to the man? Please give more background information.

Comment: "disenchanted" or "disillusioned" ?